# Installing pysox on ubuntu via pip install, cannot resolve sox.h

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, sox

I'm trying to install the pysox package using pip (easy_install throws exactly the same error) on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS.

```
$ pip install pysox
[...]
building 'pysox.sox' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c pysox/sox.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pysox/sox.o

pysox/sox.c:227:17: fatal error: sox.h: No such file or directory
```

My system has installed:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep sox
ii  libsox-fmt-all      14.3.2-3    All SoX format libraries
ii  libsox-fmt-alsa     14.3.2-3    SoX alsa format I/O library
ii  libsox-fmt-ao       14.3.2-3    SoX Libao format I/O library
ii  libsox-fmt-base     14.3.2-3    Minimal set of SoX format libraries
ii  libsox-fmt-ffmpeg   14.3.2-3    SoX ffmpeg format library
ii  libsox-fmt-mp3      14.3.2-3    SoX MP3 format library
ii  libsox-fmt-oss      14.3.2-3    SoX OSS format I/O library
ii  libsox-fmt-pulse    14.3.2-3    SoX PulseAudio format I/O library
ii  libsox1b            14.3.2-3    SoX library of audio effects and processing
ii  sox                 14.3.2-3    Swiss army knife of sound processing
```

as well as the `libasound2-plugins` and `libasound2-python` packages. I even pulled the SoX source and added ~/sox/src/sox.h to my `PATH`, all to no avail. It's true that a `find` does not locate a sox.h, even though my binaries all seem in order. the pysox source does not seem contain sox.h either.

The pysox [offical page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysox) states "Specifically you need sox.h in your include path and libsox.so and libsox.a in your link path."

But apart from compiling everything from source, I don't see how I can have those files just from the binary packages. Is it not possible to use normal package managers for this install, do I need to compile, link & include everything myself?

How does one install pysox properly on Debian/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, this was to be expected: forgot to install the dev package for SoX, namely libsox-dev. It wasn't obvious to me at first because the standard package is sox, and the lib packages are all prefaced with libsox-fmt (and there is very little documentation on this).

anyway, this is everything you'll need on a Debian machine to get the proper files in place for pip/easy_install to package manage your modules properly for SoX:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins libasound2-python libsox-fmt-all libsox-dev sox
```

Comment: On debian and ubuntu the headers are ALWAYS in a -dev package, you don't need package specific documentation for that.

Answer (score 7):

In case it helps, I had the same issue but got errors using:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins libasound2-python libsox-fmt-all libsox-dev sox
```

I did get it to work though by dropping the libasound requests, which no longer appear to be available.

This is what worked for me... the process, I think, was:

```
pip3 install sox

sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all 

sudo apt-get install sox libsox-dev 

pip3 install pysox
```

Only took me about 11 hours to work that out.